# Coming back to UIViewController doesn't trigger segue

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

I have Controller B, which sends data back to Controller A using delegate pattern but for some reason my segue doesn't trigger.

Is something stopping my segue from being triggered? How would I resolve this?

Controller B - Present Modally

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.select(sID: selectedID)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Controller A

```
func select(sID: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "editSegue", sender: self);
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editSegue" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? NewController {
                destinationVC.selectedQueryID = selectedQueryID;
                print(“test”);
            }
        }
        if segue.identifier == "selectSegue" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ControllerB {
                destinationVC.queryID = selectedQueryID;
                destinationVC.delegate = self;
            }
        }
}
```

Controller C  - Present Modally (does not present itself)

Comment: Is `NewController` Controller-C? how are you presenting controller-B? are you setting `delegate` properly?

Comment: Sorry I omitted a chunk of the prepare function. Yes `NewController` is Controller C. I'm presenting ContrB properly and upon clicking on the `addButton` function it successfully sends the data back to ContrA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the B viewcontroller, trigger upon completion of the dismiss

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
         delegate?.select(sID: selectedID)
   }
}
```

Also make sure that you are presenting B viewcontroller modally.